# KVC string conversion not working for BOOL value

Tags: objective-c, key-value-coding

Hey.  I am reading in a string from a file and attempting to use the resulting string to set a BOOL property on an object using the KVC method `-setValue:forKeyPath:`.  However, this breaks with an exception: `-[NSCFString charValue]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fff711023b0`.  I'm guessing this is because BOOL is typedef'd from char.  Is there a way around this?  Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am catching the exception, checking it's name, and then retrying with a wrapped value when needed.  Here is the code:

```
    @try
    {
        [(NSObject*)retObj setValue:[[obj keyValuePairs] objectForKey:key]
                         forKeyPath:key];
    }
    @catch (NSException * e)
    {
        if ([[e name] isEqualToString:NSInvalidArgumentException])
        {
            NSNumber* boolVal = [NSNumber numberWithBool:[[[obj keyValuePairs] objectForKey:key] boolValue]];
            [(NSObject*)retObj setValue:boolVal
                             forKeyPath:key];
        }
    }
```

Thanks anyway!

Comment: Nice way to handle the case !

Answer (score 3):

When setting a `BOOL` property using KVC, you need to pass an `NSNumber` object.  What you could do in your case is pass `[NSNumber numberWithBool:[myString boolValue]]`.  That should fix your crash.

Comment: Except I have no way of guaranteeing that what I am trying to access is a bool.  Do you think it would be reasonable to catch the exception and then re-try using a wrapped version?

Answer (score 1):

Add a simple category to your project:

```
@implementation NSString (CharValue)

- (BOOL)charValue {
    return [self isEqualToString:@"0"] ? NO : YES;
}

@end
```